# why my Gyroscope/accelerometer work only in portrait mode?

Tags: sensors, samsung-galaxy-s-advance

I have a Galaxy S Advance Gt I1970, running under Android 4.1.2 (official update). the problem is when i try to play games that require the phone sensors, for example Angry Birds Go or Frisbee Forever, the player always go to the left, but then i tried "Ridiculous Fishing" which is also a game that require sensors and it works perfectly but this game doesn't rotate the phone to the landscape mode, then i tried an application called "accelerometer test" and the result was as expected, i can control the ball when am holding the phone in portrait position bust when it's in landscape, everything is missed up. Any advice please ?

thank you

Comment: no one can answer this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by downgrading to "Ginger Bread", re-calibrate horizontal accelerometer and then 
re-update to Jelly Bean

Answer (score 0):

Your device's interface will rotate whether the app you are using was designed to (e.g. Modern combat, Dead Trigger, Browsers, etc) ,  apps that were not to intended to change between portrait or landscape won't rotate the interface of your device (e.g RealCalc, instagram, etc).